# notify with change on ontolgy (java)

Tags: java, jena, owl, ontology

I have some ontolgies (ont1, ont2, ont3) and I want to watch whether there is a modification on one of these ontologies. I searched and found (`addChangeListener`, `PropertyChangeListener`, …) but I didn't find an example with these listeners.  I found only a short description that doesn't help me a lot. I'm developing my ontology with Protege.

So, I want if there is a change on one ontology (for example update the ontology ont1 with Protege), I can be notified to synchronize the other ontologies (ont2 and ont3).

Comment: Do you have them loaded into Jena as OntModels of some sort?  I'm not sure, but I'd expect that the listeners are watching for changes to the actual Java object, not the underlying file.  Do you have reason to believe that they'd watch the actual file?

Comment: thank you for the reply. Yes, the ontology loaded as OntModel using jena. For the listeners, i don't know exactly how they work. I was thinking about mobile agent but i don't know if it's possible.

Comment: Can you link to the documentation that you found?  I'm actually not finding anything Jena specific when I search for "addChangeListener" or "PropertyChangeListener";  only general Java stuff that doesn't really have anything to do with Jena in particular.  Did you find some counterpart that's Jena or OWL specific?

Comment: i try to search about event and listener from jena to consider modification with my ontology so i found this: 
[link](http://smi-protege.stanford.edu/repos/protege/protege4/incubator/org.obolibrary.hide/trunk/src/org/obolibrary/hide/OntologySynchronizer.java)
There is Pellet 
[link](http://satin-ppl.telecom-st-etienne.fr/cgravier/jaise/CACGExample.java)

Comment: that first link isn't based on jena though, it's using the OWLAPI.